# Reconvert numeric date to POSIXct R

Tags: r, posixct

I have a date that I convert to a numeric value and want to convert back to a date afterwards.

Converting date to numeric:

```
date1 = as.POSIXct('2017-12-30 15:00:00')
date1_num = as.numeric(date1)
# 1514646000
```

Reconverting numeric to date:

```
as.Date(date1_num, origin = '1/1/1970')
# "4146960-12-12"
```

What am I missing with the reconversion? I'd expect the last command to return my original `date1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the numeric vector is created from an object with time component, reconversion can also be in the same way i.e. first to `POSIXct` and then wrap with `as.Date`

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(date1_num, origin = '1970-01-01'))
#[1] "2017-12-30"
```

Comment: Excellent, and how would I reconstruct the time of the original `date1` "15:00:00"?

Comment: @ben_aaron  Just remove the `as.Date` wrapping `as.POSIXct(date1_num, origin = '1970-01-01')#
[1] "2017-12-30 15:00:00 EST"`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `anytime()` and `anydate()` from the [anytime](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package:

```
R> pt <- anytime("2017-12-30 15:00:00")
R> pt
[1] "2017-12-30 15:00:00 CST"
R>
R> anydate(pt)
[1] "2017-12-30"
R>
R> as.numeric(pt)
[1] 1514667600
R>
R> anydate(as.numeric(pt))
[1] "2017-12-30"
R>
```

Answer (score 2):

`POSIXct` counts the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch, while `Date` counts the number of days. So you can recover the date by dividing by `(60*60*24)` (let's ignore leap seconds), or convert back to `POSIXct` instead.

```
as.Date(as.numeric(date1)/(60*60*24), origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2017-12-30"

as.POSIXct(as.numeric(date1),origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2017-12-30 15:00:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *lubridate* :

```
lubridate::as_datetime(1514646000)
[1] "2017-12-30 15:00:00 UTC"
```